# Why are my Vue/Nuxt Select field states valid by default?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a variety of HTML select elements inside of Nuxt.js. I'm also using Vuelidate for validation and this is working as expected. This is a typical select box in my form:

```html
    <select
      id="location"
      name="location"
      v-model="form.location"
      @blur="$v.form.location.$touch()"
      :class="{error: appendErrorClass($v.form.location)}"
    >
      <option :value="null" hidden>Choose...</option>
      <option 
        v-for="(item, index) in $store.state.quotes.data.practiceStates"
        :key="index"
        :value="item.data">
          {{item.display}}
      </option>
    </select>
```

Before selecting any of the options, I'm noticing the following on all select fields.

[image: Select Box Validity settings]

I've tried removing any Vue magic on a test select field to see if the same results happen.

```html
      <select id="location1" name="location1">
        <option value="" hidden>Choose...</option>
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="two">two</option>
        <option value="three">three</option>
      </select>
```

Still seeing `valid: true`. Is there anything I'm overlooking that would cause the validity to default to true? Thanks in advance for any help or guidance on this issue.

UPDATE For Clarification:
Vuelidate validation works just fine. The issue I'm dealing with is the select field property `Validity.validate`. I only mention Vuelidate to give full context.

Answer (score 0):

`HTML Select` is a sort of "strange" form element in that validity is typically checking to see if there's a readable value. Since a select always has something picked, it validates...

This is different from say a telephone input that has a specific pattern required to be valid.

I haven't used Vuelidate specifically, but I read the docs as saying, if you left the `v-model="form.location"` there's a good chance it's simply validating that a value exists so **Any selcted item** would qualify.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the validity of my select fields outside of a Vue environment default to false. The information on vuelidate above may be misleading. The main goal is to style the color of the options when the `select:valid` css pseudo-selectors. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Well that uses HTML's test for validity NOT anything in Vue. And as long as an Option has `value=""` it should test as true

Comment: I thought so, too. I found a work around to my issue. It doesn't answer the original question I posted, but it at least gets me to the end result I was hoping to achieve. I will post my answer soon. Again, I do appreciate you taking the time to help me out on this.

Comment: Yeah I'm interested to see where you landed. Validating selects is a common problem

Answer (score 0):

In my original post, I referenced the dynamic style based on the vuelidate library: `:class="{error: appendErrorClass($v.form.location)}"`

@PierreSaid responded to this post and later deleted his/her reply. Turns out, his response was helpful in pointing me to some Vuelidate attributes that were able to assist in a workaround for my issue. Thank you, PierreSaid.

I have since updated that dynamic class to be a mixin that looks like this:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    appendErrorAndValidityClass(field) {
      return {
        error: field.$error,
        invalid: field.$invalid,
      };
    }
  }
};
```

After importing the mixin into the Vue partial, my select box looks like this:

```js
<select
  id="location"
  name="location"
  v-model="form.location"
  @blur="$v.form.location.$touch()"
  :class="appendErrorAndValidityClass($v.form.location)"
>
```

This appends a class of `invalid` when the select field has not been updated. It also updates the error style accordingly. Now, I can assign styles for when the select field has an invalid class. This solves the overall issue for me. Thanks for your help PierreSaid and Bryce.